# Js need to edit on it

Tags: javascript

This code must highlight duplicated words in page I want to highlight duplicated numbers not words

```
var text = $('table');
var arr = [];

//Step 1: Getting All words from table
var words = text.each(function(){
   let val = $(this).text().replace(/\n|\r/g,' ').split(' ').filter(Boolean);
   arr.push(...val)
})
console.log("arr", arr)

//Step 2: Finding duplicate words
let duplicate = arr.filter(function(value,index,self){ return (self.indexOf(value) !== index && isNaN(parseInt(value)) && value.match(/[A-Za-z]/) !== null)})
console.log("duplicate",duplicate)

//Step 3: Marking duplicate words in each row
$('td').each(function(){
   let val = $(this).text();
   let openMark = '<mark>'
   let closeMark = '</mark>'
   duplicate.forEach(v => {
      if(val.indexOf(v) !== -1){
          var html = $(this).html().replace(v, openMark + v + closeMark)
          $(this).html(html)
      }
   })
})
```

I hope anyone can help me

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Comment: `arr.filter((value,index,self) self.indexOf(value) !== index && !isNaN(parseInt(value)) && value.test(/^[0-9]+$/))`

Comment: You may need to change `.split(' ')` to `.split('')` or use spread: `[...val]`